# Can you use Druidcraft to grow edible food for an herbivorous animal?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cantrips, animals, food-and-drink

One of the effects of the [*druidcraft*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/druidcraft) cantrip is the following:

> You instantly make a flower blossom, a seed pod open, or a leaf bud
>   bloom.

I am wondering whether you could use that effect to grow food (ex: grass) for an herbivorous animal (ex: donkey), provided that you have a fertile enough ground and the required seeds (that you simply want to grow instantly with the cantrip).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## No, this would not significantly speed up food production

So this is really outside the realm of pure rules, but I would say no for the following reasons:

### It doesn't create adult plants

> a flower blossom, a seed pod open, or a leaf bud bloom

Note how none of these effects say anything about a plant growing at all.

It says seed pods **open** which means the casing splits and maybe a small root comes out of it. But no adult plant forms. Same with the flower blossoming (just means the flower opens) and leaf bud blooming (just means an already formed leaf unfurls).

At best you could argue that there would be a slight increase in the speed of farming these seeds, but in the scale of things it would be miniscule.

In order for this to work, adult mature plants must somehow be created and this spell does not do that. It would still take days or even much longer to produce food.

### It is not much faster than normal farming

This cantrip only works on 1 seed at a time. Even if it instantly produced plants that is going to be a very long time casting spells just to get one meal.

Not to mention that, since it doesn't create adult plants or speed up their growth, you still have to wait for them to grow normally!

### It doesn't fit compared to the other effects of druidcraft

Compare it to the other effects in the spell which are all very minor and very specific. It would seem very much out of line with the rest of the effects in this spell to attribute this one with the ability, however arduous, to create food when it really isn't readily read from the given text.

### Other spells are made to do this exact thing (and they take resources)

Compare the strength of this effect to other spells like *goodberry* and *create food and water* which are both spells that require spell slots to be used. It would seem to be an unbalanced approach to allow a cantrip to replicate those effects.

And, in fact, [goodberry](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/goodberry) is a spell made for this exact thing. So, really use that instead.

Comment: also a comparison to good-berry which does produce food, but is a level 1 spell would be another nail in this particular coffin.

Comment: I know no one cares but Goodberry is written as a conjuration even though it is listed as a Transmutation, check with your DM on whether schools of magic matter to them.

Answer (score 13):

### Yes, but it won't be very effective

The spell doesn't set any restrictions on the duration of the opening or blooming, so it's safe to say that the plant growth is permanent and "real". In comparison, the Create Food and Water spell says that the food only stays good for 24 hours. Therefore, if you plant a ton of seeds and cast this on each one, you can, in principle, speed up the farming process.

However, Druidcraft only works on a **single** flower, seed pod, or leaf bud blossom at a time. This means that it will take you 6 seconds per germinated seed pod. I don't know how familiar you are with farming and growing hay, but animals need to eat quite a lot of it in order to survive. Adding your extra 1 germination per 6 seconds will make a trivial difference in the amount of grass you're growing, and you're basically going to have to be an ordinary farmer. Additionally, most animals eat mature plants, but Druidcraft only jump starts the germination process, and doesn't speed up growth.

### Use Goodberry instead

The Goodberry spell states,

> Eating a berry restores 1 hit point, and the berry provides enough nourishment to sustain a creature for one day.

It's a 1st level spell, so it uses more resources, but one goodberry is enough to sustain your donkey for a day without having to resort to farming.

Comment: Ended up accepting the other answer because it talks about adult plants.

Comment: This answer isn't correct; you can't grow seeds with the spell, it only affects flowers, seed pods, and leaf buds, all of which are things that are growing on an *already existing **adult** plant*. If you plant seeds and cast this spell, it will do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The effect you want, I believe, is a very constrained application of the instantaneous version of plant growth.

Find a patch of something that will work as feed grass or whatever, then have all.of it it can be right now. Maybe drop seeds, use druidcraft to activate them, then plant growth to produce instant done.

Comment: Hello and welcome! You can take the [tour] for a quick site intro. I am having trouble parsing the last part of the answer. Could you recheck that this is what you intended to state or otherwise clarify the meaning? Thank you for contributing!